# Shell iterate over directories and move all their files

Tags: shell

I want to iterate over a set of directories and move all their contents to another location. What I tried was this:

```
for d in */
do
    mv d/* /other/location/
done
```

but this did not work. Why is d not the directories, so that `[directory]/*` will target all files in that directory? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment to answer:

You just need to dereference the `d` variable:

```
for d in */
do
    mv $d/* /other/location/
done
```